# Unity issues suddenly in an Ubuntu 16.04LTS installation

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash

I suddenly had my unity crashed. Dashboard and launcher have suddenly stopped functioning.

I saw the following thread:
[Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears][1])

However when executing the command

```
DISPLAY=:0 ccsm &
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
"*ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol: FT_Reference_Face*"
```

I also tried to reinstall unity by running

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
```

but the same issues appear.

Any ideas on what is the problem?

Comment: Switch to a tty-session (Ctrl-Alt-F1), log there, so type this: `export DISPLAY=:0 && unity --replace &` Inspect messages you have.